# Create a join on range from one table to a value from another table SQL server

Tags: sql-server, join

So, I need to write a join between two tables whose structures are as below.

[image]

The user will provide the value BATCHID and this will get the corresponding value of VARIABLENAME which has two properties BATCHSTART and BATCHEND which are of type datetime. Now the condition is that the value of TIMESTAMP from the table NUMERICLOG should lie in between VARIABLENAME.BATCHSTART and VARIABLENAME.BATCHEND.

Now, because there is no common column between the two tables, I am not able to figure out how to do this.

Since, I don't have much experience with database queries, am I missing something very obvious? Please help.

Comment: What columns you want to return from the numericlog table?

Comment: DATAVALUE and TIMESTAMP..

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear you goal here, be it validating input within the NUMERICLOG table based upon the BATCH_VARIABLES START/END values, or if it is the reverse.

Ultimately you are trying to perform query that returns a range of TIMESTAMP datetime entries `BETWEEN` two dates.

Have a look at this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/79e75/2/0), which captures I believe captures the gist of your goal, of a BETWEEN query.